# Lossy audio encoding java

Tags: java, audio, encoding

What (stable) encoding libraries exist that can encode an uncompressed or lossless audio file to a common lossy format such as aac, mp3 or ogg?

If it is possible to do this without a library, that would be a valid option, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vorbis-java](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis-java/) is my recommendation, because it is free and avoids the patent / licensing issues you may come across with aac or mp3.

[LAMEOnJ](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/) is a Java api for mp3 en/decoding, but you'll need to get the LAME library separately, due to the licensing concerns.